# Javascript: match string to object and return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given that I have the following string

```
string= "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2"

var stringReplace = string.replace(/goal/g, "iGoal").replace(/planet/g, "iPlanet").replace(/Environment/g, "iEnvironment").replace(/HealthWellness/g, "iHealthWellness").replace(/SustainableInfrastructure/g, "iSustainableInfrastructure").replace(/ResponsibleConsumption/g, "iResponsibleConsumption");
```

My replace code works, but I think it can be improved upon, so if I want to create an object such as;

```
    stringReplace = 
    {
      items: 
     {
      "goal":"iGoal",
      "planet":"iPlanet",
      "people":"iPeople",
      "Inclusion":"iInclusion",
      "Environment":"iEnvironment",
      "HealthWellness":"iHealthWellness",
      "SustainableInfrastructure":"iSustainableInfrastructure",
      "ResponsibleConsumption":"iResponsibleConsumption"
    }
};
```

what would be the equivalent of the `.replace()` function in this case?

Comment: there is a difference between your examples, in the first one there is no replace for people->iPeople

Comment: Just want to make sure before writing an answer: there is also missing inclusion -> iInclusion.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to _specifically_ do it this way (or even replace these variables) or if you maybe just want to replace any `abc` and `Abc` at the start of a word with `iAbc`. In the latter case you could just do `string.replace(/\b[a-z]/gi, c => 'i' + c.toUpperCase())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @CherryDT that your example is not very clear. Here are some answers for different interpretations.

#### Interpretation 1

If you want to use a predefined list of "replacement instructions" you could go with a loop over each element of your instructions.

```js
Object.keys(stringReplace.items).forEach(x => string = string.replaceAll(x, stringReplace.items[x]));
```

#### Interpretation 2

If you want to generically **i-prefix + uppercase** specific words, you could use:

```js
string = string.replace(new RegExp("(" + Object.keys(stringReplace.items).join("|") + ")", "g"), s => "i" + s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1));
```

You could use an array instead of the `stringReplace` object in that case because the values are not used here.

#### Interpretation 3

If you know which words potentially exist in the string and you want to replace all of them with their **i-prefix + uppercase** equivalent, you can use ([CherryDT's answer](//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243160/javascript-match-string-to-object-and-return-value#comment120610999_68243160)):

```js
string = string.replace(/\b[a-z]/gi, c => 'i' + c.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little unclear, but it looks like you want to discard the multiple numbered elements, ('goal01', 'goal02', etc) as well as the values.

That being the case, you can simply match all words excluding digits and symbols, and simplify your multiple `replace()` calls to a single replace adding an 'i' and making the first letter uppercase, then reducing the results to an object.

```js
const
  string = "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2",
  object = string
    .match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)
    .reduce((a, s) => ({ ...a, [s]: `i${s.replace(/^./, m => m.toUpperCase())}` }), {});

console.log(object);
```